# Issue with variable length during import/export

Tags: excel

I'm new to R but I am wondering if this problem I have is fixable in R.

I want to read in many excel files, and while many of them are in the same form, they differ in where their headers begin.  Some begin on the 29th row some on the 30th and some on the 28th.

I want to know if it is possible to have R determine which row to start its import by looking in column A of the excel sheet for the word 'Date' which would be the unilateral key of where to begin importing across all excel sheets.

Thanks,
Tim

Comment: This is possible, because R has programming features...however, it would not be trivial with the base code. There may be a package to assist with this. But, I think the moderators are going to move this question to a different forum...as it isn't stats related.

Comment: Shoot, sorry I should've seen that. I'm new, but thanks for the tip Gregg.